# Obtain the text from a text field matrix

Tags: java, swing, matrix, textfield

I have created a text field matrix, but I can't obtain the text that it is being typed into those text fields. I am only getting access to the text field object itself within the matrix, no to the actual text inside those text fields.

Here's the entire code. My main language is spanish, so some anotations are in spanish, and some phrases. Under the code i'll write my main problema:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FrmArregloControles extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public FrmArregloControles() {
        initComponents();
        iniciarComponentes();
    }    
    private void iniciarComponentes() {
        byte numRen = Byte.parseByte(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "¿Número de Renglones?")),
             numCol = Byte.parseByte(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "¿Número de Columnas?"));
        int [][] intMatriz = new int[numRen][numCol];
        txtMatriz = new JTextField[numRen][numCol];
        String txt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"¿Qué ponemos?");

        if (numRen >= 1 && numCol >= 1) {
            lblRen = new JLabel[numRen];
            lblCol = new JLabel[numCol];

            for (byte r = 0; r < txtMatriz.length; r++) {//for controla los renglones (r)
                // creacion del vector de etiquetas lblRen
                lblRen[r] = new JLabel();
                // CONFIURACION DE PROPIEDADES PARA EL VECTOR PARA ETIQUTAS DE RENGLONES
                lblRen[r].setBounds(new Rectangle(15, 
                                                  15 + (25 + 10) * (r + 1), 
                                                  40, 25));

                lblRen[r].setText("[" + (r+1) + "]");
                lblRen[r].setBorder(border);
                lblRen[r].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
              //Adición de la etiqueta a la forma
                this.add(lblRen[r]);
                for (byte c = 0; c < txtMatriz[r].length; c++){
                  // creacion del vector de etiquetas lblRen
                lblCol[c] = new JLabel();
                // CONFIURACION DE PROPIEDADES PARA EL VECTOR PARA ETIQUTAS DE COLUMNAS
                lblCol[c].setBounds(new Rectangle(15 + (lblRen[0].getWidth() + 10) * (c + 1), 
                                                  15, 
                                                  40, 25));

                lblCol[c].setText("[" + (c+1) + "]");
                lblCol[c].setBorder(border);
                lblCol[c].setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                lblCol[c].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
              //Adición de la etiqueta a la forma
                this.add(lblCol[c]);

              //Creación de matriz de campos de texto
                txtMatriz[r][c] = new JTextField();
              //Configuración de propiedades de campos de texto
                txtMatriz[r][c].setBounds(new Rectangle(15 + (lblRen[0].getWidth() + 10) * (c+1), 
                                                        15 + (lblRen[0].getHeight() + 10) * (r + 1), 
                                                        40, 25));

                txtMatriz[r][c].setToolTipText("Campo " + (r + 1) + ", " + (c + 1));
                txtMatriz[r][c].setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));
                this.add(txtMatriz[r][c]);
                txtMatriz[r][c].setText(txt);
                txtMatriz[r][c].getText();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tamaño Invalido");
        }

        btnCapturar.setBounds (new Rectangle(((((40 + (numRen * 20))- 30) + (numRen * 10)/2)), 
                                                ((numCol*35) + 50 ), 
                                                 100, 25));

        this.add(btnCapturar);
        btnCapturar.addActionListener(this);
    }


            //Button's function
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(txtMatriz));
        }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FrmArregloControles().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
//DECLARACIÓN DE CONTROLES
    JLabel lblRen[], lblCol[];
    JTextField txtMatriz[][];
    JButton btnCapturar = new JButton("Capturar");
    javax.swing.border.Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1);

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

What I want is to get the *txtMatriz*'s text from every single text field inside of it, and assign them into a different matrix, but an int type matrix. I've tried some methods, but the closer I've get, is when I've noticed that a JTextField can't be transformed into an int. So saying this, I'm assuming that I can't get to the texts of those text fields by using the Integer.parseInt method. So, summarizing, I need help to transform the txtMatriz, into a intMatriz

Comment: It would be quite useful to see the output. I'm not sure what you mean by "memory allocation of the object, or something like this", and I'd dare say you're not 100% sure yourself.

Comment: This is the output when I execute System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(txtMatrix));

Comment: [[javax.swing.JTextField[,65,50,40x25,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@1469254,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=,disabledTextColor=DerivedColor(color=142,143,145 parent=nimbusDisabledText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=142,143,145,editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=...

Comment: It goes on and on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try to loop through each array with a for loop?

```
for(byte i = 0; i < intMatrix.length; i++){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intMatrix[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*[Note, I've changed my original answer now that the question has been greatly expanded, including full source code, allowing me to resolve the issue directly]*

Ok. It's rather weird because your original code sample, whilst no longer present, was sort of on the right track, so I don't quite understand why it didn't work. Anyway, here's what you need to do:

1. Move the int[][] intMatrix declaration to become an instance variable, just like `txtMatriz` is. I prefer to place them above the constructor:

   `int [][] intMatriz;`
2. Similarly, once you know the matrix dimensions, initialise:

   `intMatriz = new int[numRen][numCol];`
3. Finally, update the actionPerformed as follows:

   ```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       for (byte r = 0; r < txtMatriz.length; r++) {
           for (byte c = 0; c < txtMatriz[r].length; c++) {
               intMatriz[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(txtMatriz[r][c].getText());
           }
       }
       System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(intMatriz));
   }
   ```

When I do those changes I see an output like:

```
[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 5, 6, 6]]
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the problem, I've just edited the publication, and added more detail of the code. Hope you can give some more help out.

Comment: @IrmanRodríguez That's now much clearer. I've edited my answer accordingly.